# Overriding TableMapper splits

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am using the following code to read from a table which has its row keys having a format of "epoch_meter" where epoch is the long representation of the date time in seconds and meter is a meter number.

```
Job jobCalcDFT = Job.getInstance(confCalcIndDeviation);

jobCalcDFT.setJarByClass(CalculateIndividualDeviation.class);

Scan scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(startSeconds) + "_"),
Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(endSeconds + 1) + "_"));

scan.setCaching(500);

scan.setCacheBlocks(false);

scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("readings"), Bytes.toBytes("halfhourly"));

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("meterreadings", 
scan, EmitDFTMapper.class,
MeterIdFrequencyKey.class, 
ComplexWritable.class, jobCalcDFT);
```

I can mention start row and end row. But I am not being able to find much information on how to controls the splits.

So, the meterreadings table has 100 million rows. The value in each row is just 32 bytes (a float value). That would be around 3.2 GB (I am not considering the space for the keys - if I consider the keys then considering each key is a string value of around 20 to 30 characters - that will probably add 60 bytes per row). Now I am not sure now internally HBase will compress this, but if I do not consider compressing, that 3.2GB should be split up into quite a few mappers. Comparing with HDFS splitting, if I consider a 128MB split, it should give me around 25 TableMappers.

Now the startrow endrow combination I am using, is checking for around 1/25th of that 100 million recods. And, consequently, I am seeing only 2 TableMappers being used for this job. Don't know if that's how the calculation works, its a guess.

But it is still around 4 million rows, and two mappers is making the job run very slow. Can anyone tell me how can I change the splitting (now that TableInputFormat is deprecated) such that there are more TableMappers reading the rows.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your own TableMapReduceUtil [(or copy HBase's)](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.java?view=markup) and use a  subclass [TableInputFormatBase](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormatBase.html) and override getSplits to return more splits than 1 per region (the default behavior) - you can find the code for TableInputFormatBase [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormatBase.java?view=markup)

By the way the TableInputFormat that is depracated is in org.apache.hadoop.hbase.**mapred** namespace not the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.**mapreduce** namespace

Comment: Arnon, thanks. I will give it a go and let you know if that worked. And then I will mark this as answered.

Comment: Arnon, just to let you know, I am still at it. I am actually trying to see if I can get it working with something similar to what was suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353911/extending-hadoops-tableinputformat-to-scan-with-a-prefix-used-for-distribution/17952223. That will be much simpler that writing my own TableMapReduceUtil. Do you know any reason, why that approach would not work in my problem?. I am however yet to get it working as I keep on getting ClassNotFoundException on TableMapper when I use ..true,MyTableInputFormat.class as the last two params of initTableMapperJob

Comment: Sorry yes you are right you can pass an alternate InputtFormat to the TableMapReduceUtil (I didn't notice that constructor) - you'd still want to extend TableInputFormatBase and make sure you are in the mapreduce (not mapred) space

Comment: OK - after fishing for several days, it seems I know why I was getting class not found exception. The addDependencyJars method in TableMapReduceUtil is not adding the TableMapper class and hence the hbase.jar is not being copied. So - I followed Arnons suggestion, had my own TableMapReduceUtil (with a single line change) and it worked.  `public static void addDependencyJars(Job job) throws IOException {
try {
addDependencyJars(job.getConfiguration(),
TableMapper.class,
com.google.protobuf.Message.class,
......
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {throw new.. ` I overrode revision 1342856.