# ClassNotFoundException on TableMapper when I use my own TableInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, cloudera

I am trying to use my own TableInputFormat for a MapReduceJob in the following way

`TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("mytable", 
    MyScan, 
    MyMapper.class,
    MyKey.class, 
    MyValue.class, 
    myJob,true, MyTableInputFormat.class);`

When I run the job, I get a ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper - any idea why ?

if I do not use the last two parameters of initTableMapperJob, then there is no ClassNotFoundException (but obviously that defeats the purpose)

I am struggling on this for few days now.
This is somewhere someone did the same thing [Extending Hadoop's TableInputFormat to scan with a prefix used for distribution of timestamp keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353911/extending-hadoops-tableinputformat-to-scan-with-a-prefix-used-for-distribution/17952223), but I am not being able to ask the question on that thread.

I am working on a Cloudera Cluster 4.3.0 with Hadoop 2

Adding the stacktrace error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ....
```

Thanks a lot for helping

Regards

Comment: Adding the stacktrace `error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
....
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Overriding TableMapper splits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945990/overriding-tablemapper-splits). So I overrode TableMapReduceUtil and added TableMapper.class to the addDependencyJars method. Then I proceeded in the same way 

    `MyTableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("MyTable", // input table
    myScan, 
    MyMapper.class, 
    MyKey.class, 
    MyValue.class, 
    myJob,
    true,CustomSplitTableInputFormat.class);`

Where CustomSplitTableInputFormat extends TableInputFormat

Comment: Considering the fact that you have answered your question, can I assume you have solved your problem?

Comment: jtheRocker, it is not letting me do that - will try in 2 days. Thanks.